# Python: Suppress exponential format (i.e. 9e-10) in float to string conversion?

Tags: python, floating-point, string-formatting

I want to use python to write code for another language which doesn't understand exponentially formatted floats. Is there an easy way to get python to, when converting floats to strings, use long-form notation (I.E. 0.000000009 instead of 9e-9)? I tried '%(foo)f', but it cuts the decimal short (0.00000).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like

```
"%.16f" % f
```

This will still use exponential format if the number is too small, so you have to treat this case separately, for example

```
"%.16f" % f if f >= 1e-16 else "0.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a specific format specifier, e.g.:

```
>>> f=9*(10**-9)
>>> str(f)
'9e-09'
>>> "%.23f" % f
'0.00000000900000000000000'
```

UPDATE (thanks to @Sven): The amount of digits you want to use depends on the magnitude of the number. if you have large numbers (like several trillions) you won't need any decimals, obviously. for tiny numbers you need more. 'tis an ugly representation indeed.

Comment: The IEEE standard guarantees that a representation of the first 17 significant decimal digits will uniquely determine a double precision number.  But we are dealing with fixed comma representations here, so this guarantee is not useful in this context -- just try numbers like 0.000333333, and you will need more digits.

Comment: @Sven: oh right, it is 17 significant digits, not 17 decimal places. ill update the answer to reflect that